# How to create a list of counts from a unique list and a Counter object?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, counter

I have a `Counter()` object that gives me count occurrences of a list of strings. And I have a unique list of strings. And I need to yield a list of counts from the counter and then put zeros to the other string instances that have 0 counts.

I can do it as the following but can I achieve the same `z` list in a more efficient/pythonic way?

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(['abc','def','abc'])
uniq = sorted(set(['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi', 'jkl','jkl']))
z = [x[i] for i in uniq]
```

Output

```
>>> z
[2, 1, 0, 0]
>>> uniq
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Actually the ultimate aim is to get an `np.array(z)` and `np.array(uniq)`

Comment: My opinion is that yours is the best way.  If your second list is long, you could replace `np.array(sorted(set(...)))` with `np.unique(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use the `Counter`'s `update` method to add 0 to all of the keys in the unique list

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter(['abc','def','abc'])
>>> y = ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi', 'jkl','jkl']
>>> x.update(dict.fromkeys(y, 0))
```

So that `x` now contains the keys and values you want.

Or, if you want to avoid the construction of the intermediate `dict`, the slightly longer:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter(['abc','def','abc'])
>>> y = ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi', 'jkl','jkl']
>>> for k in y:
        x[k] += 0
```

Comment: Nice, then you can do `u, z = np.array(zip(x.items).T`.  Still not as fast as OP though.